llap within datatool changing column aligment
I am using updated TL2024 and datatool to create a tabular from a CSV file (MWE below).

I'd like to insert the contents from foo column in front of the first column without affecting the table format, I mean, like marginal notes out of tabular.
I know that an extra column could be a solution but my CSV and tabular are complex and I'd like to avoid changing a lot of column width computations to adjust everything.
So, I tried to use \llap as shown bellow but no success. It works with l instead of p column alignment.

Q: So, what is the easiest way to do that?
ps: If I'm not wrong my approach worked last year with TL2023. See the numbers on the left:

MWE
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a5paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

%% table data
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age,IQ,foo
Albert,Einstein,133,210.12,a
Marie,Curie,145,220.12,b
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{table}{scientists.csv}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tabular}{
    @{} p{.15\linewidth} p{.15\linewidth} p{.15\linewidth} p{.15\linewidth}
}
     name & surname & age & iq \\
    \hline
    \DTLforeach*{table}{\name=name, \surname=surname, \age=age, \iq=IQ, \foo=foo}%
    {\DTLiffirstrow{}{\tabularnewline}%
%    \llap{\foo}%     <-- not working
     \name & \surname & \age & \iq 
    }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


you can test your theory about last year on overleaf if you don't have a local install of tl2023, say.

@cfr, good idea. I've just tested and no success even with TL23 and TL22. So, now I don't know how I created that table.

...use \leavevmode\llap{\foo}, or \makebox[0pt][r]{\foo}.

@Werner, thanks. I'd tried with \hbox to 0pt but now let me try yours.

You're mistaken about the output being as expected with older TeX distributions. In the meantime you've discovered why using \llap can be dangerous.
The material typeset with \llap doesn't start horizontal mode (LR mode in LaTeX manual parlance).
Since you're using (not sure why) a p column, the material after \llap will start a paragraph.
You can use \llap if you know well about it; it won't be a risk in a nonparagraph column.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a5paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

%% table data
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name,surname,age,IQ,foo
Albert,Einstein,133,210.12,a
Marie,Curie,145,220.12,b
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{table}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
    @{} *{4}{w{l}{.15\linewidth}} @{}
}
     name & surname & age & iq \\
    \hline
    \DTLforeach*{table}{\name=name, \surname=surname, \age=age, \iq=IQ, \foo=foo}%
    {\DTLiffirstrow{}{\tabularnewline}%
    \llap{\foo\space}
     \name & \surname & \age & \iq 
    }
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{
    @{} p{.15\linewidth} p{.15\linewidth} p{.15\linewidth} p{.15\linewidth}
}
     name & surname & age & iq \\
    \hline
    \DTLforeach*{table}{\name=name, \surname=surname, \age=age, \iq=IQ, \foo=foo}%
    {\DTLiffirstrow{}{\tabularnewline}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\foo\space}
     \name & \surname & \age & \iq 
    }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



Very nice. I didn't know about the \llap and horizontal mode relation. Some cell contents are wider, so I would like to have line breaks, this is why I'm using p column. The MWE is just to exemplify. If there is a better approach, please, let me know. Thanks.
